# Usability Tests of Widely-Used Software

Tags: testing, usability, usability-testing

Does anyone know where I can go to find the results of usability testing of widely used software?

I want to be able to make informed decisions about:

- which bits of existing packages to copy in my software
- how to choose between multiple packages (programs, components, etc).

Really, I would be grateful for anything here.
I'm interested in: websites, office software, email clients, you name it.
I want objective, empirical information about what's good and what's not in specific instances.

This question is inspired by [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416766/is-markdown-friendly-enough-for-non-technical-users#416905) to [this question about markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416766/is-markdown-friendly-enough-for-non-technical-users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[useit.com](http://www.useit.com/) gives out awards for 10 Best X on a semiregular basis, e.g., [10 Best Intranets of 2009](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/intranet_design.html), [10 Best Application UIs of 2008](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/application-design.html), etc.

In case I didn't make it clear, useit.com is the web site for [Jakob Nielsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakob_Nielsen_(usability_consultant)), and the Top 10 lists are the results of usability studies the [NN/g](http://www.nngroup.com/about/) conducts.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you can try the [Interface Hall of Shame](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/shame.htm), just as well as the one of [Fame](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/fame.htm).